# Search/Highlight a particular word in word document

Tags: c#, search, ms-word

I am able to search/highlight a particular word in a word document with my code. But below is the problem I am facing.

If the search word is "it" then it searches for "it" and also in w"it"nessed. I want to search only the word "it". How do i solve this issue?

```
foreach (Word.Range w in doc.Words)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
    {
        XmlAttributeCollection xmlattrc = xmlnode[i].Attributes;
        object text = xmlnode[i].FirstChild.InnerText;//search words are in xml file

        if (w.Text.Trim() == text.ToString())
        {
            w.Font.Bold = 1;
            w.HighlightColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkYellow;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use String.Compare Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/e6883c06.aspx

```
public static int Compare(
    string strA,
    string strB,
    StringComparison comparisonType
)
```

[EDIT] To seach for words with beginning and ending space try to use RegEx, for example:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex myReg ex = new Regex("^\s.*\s$");
bool bFound = myRegex.IsMatch(text);
```

Comment: It dint help me. i need to seach for words with beguining and ending space. I think this ll solve my issue. is there a way to search likewise?

Comment: Of course, you can use the regular expressions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228595.aspx

Comment: @Robin: I have added an example of RegEx in my answer, pls take a look